# Create Random non words

Tags: command-line, dd, output

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=a.log bs=1M count=2
```

Question: if this code ^ gives me random numbers, how can I get random non-words (unintelligible) such as “hgcqw”.

Question 2: Can the shuf command be used in conjunction with the dd command?

Thanks!

6/21 Update. (Father's day)

@ Serg My goal was to obtain numbers at first. Say, random two digits numbers from 01-100. Give the command and run the code. Eventually it will give me 14, 17, 21, 35 ( I am making up what random numbers I get). Next, I wanted to get an average of those numbers. In this case the average would be 21.75 (22). The goal would be to stop the loop until it finds a specific average I was looking for. In this case it would be 25. My second goal was to get random words and then get a count of what words were used.

@ terdon

A word is "buck", "duck," or "good old luck." Basically anything found in the dictionary.  The lengths would be any yet if we were to constrain the limit to 5 letters, I wouldn't mind learning how?

What's a word? I presume you mean only a-z and A-Z but what lengths? Would liwyduglashvdbalishfvgapivflakhf be a word? How about ksjdas-asd-asd-asd? - can be in words. Please edit and clarify. –  terdon yesterday

Comment: What's your goal ?

Comment: What's a word? I presume you mean only `a-z` and `A-Z` but what lengths? Would `liwyduglashvdbalishfvgapivflakhf` be a word? How about `ksjdas-asd-asd-asd`? `-` can be in words. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: @ Serg My goal was to obtain numbers at first.  Say, random two digits numbers from 01-100.  Give the command and run the code.  Eventually it will give me 14, 17, 21, 35 ( I am making up what random numbers I get). Next, I wanted to get an average of those numbers.  In this case the average would be  21.75 (22).  The goal would be to stop the loop until it finds a specific average I was looking for.  In this case it would be 25. My second goal was to get random words and then get a count of what words were used.

Comment: @ricomon: Thanks for adding more detail to your question. Unfortunately it's still unclear. Please give a precise description of the expected output with one ore more examples! On top of that, I feel, that it's becoming more a question about programming than about Bash, so you may get better answers on [SO], but in the current state they will likely close your question for the same reason: lack of clarity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generate a random alphabetic character.

```
tr -cd '[:alpha:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w1 | head -n1
```

Generate a random alphabetic string 10 characters in length.

```
tr -cd '[:alpha:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w10 | head -n1
```

Some of the alternative POSIX character classes to use instead of the `alpha` in `[:alpha:]` are:

<sub>alnum - alphanumeric characters

alpha - alphabetic characters

digit - digits

graph - visible characters

lower - lowercase characters

upper - uppercase characters</sub>

Generate random numbers in a specific range (example 1-10).

```
shuf -i 1-10 -n1
```

Compared to the first two bash examples, the `shuf` command offers fewer options for generating random strings , although `shuf` can be used to generate random permutations.

Comment: With GNU coreutils, "fold -w$N | head -n1" can be simplified to "head -c$N".

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> dd if=/dev/urandom of=a.log bs=1M count=2
> ```

This doesn't give you random numbers. This gives you random *bytes*. You could encode it to numbers:

```
hexdump -v -e '"%d\n"' /dev/urandom | dd of=a.log bs=1M count=2
```

(The earlier version used `od`, but `od`'s output format is rather inflexible.)

Using `/dev/random` directly might be rather wasteful, since it is a stream of bytes. You could encode it to `base64`, and then strip out non-alphabets, which should still get you, on an average, 80 % of the input data:

```
base64 /dev/urandom | tr -cd '[[:alpha:][:space:]]'
```

This tends to leave rather long lines. You could, instead, replace numbers with newlines:

```
base64 /dev/urandom | sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]\+/\n/g'
```

Comment: This is *way* faster than my version, however have you checked the output? It doesn't contain spaces, and it's randomly splitted into lines.

Comment: @kos of `base64`?

Comment: Yes,  it prints lines of a lenght about the width of the terminal not containing spaces

Comment: @kos `base64` dumps lines of 80 characters, no spaces (deleting digits leaves shorter lines). You'll have to use `fold` or something to get even splitting.

Comment: It's not mentioned in the question whether it should be an unique line or not, nor its lenght, so that's not my point (I just tought it was weird - makes sense after your explanation), but spaces are requested (since it asks for words)

Comment: @kos each line a word?

Comment: Yea, fair enough. Perhaps it's just that I pictured the thing a little differently in mind (i.e. a non line-separated sequence of words of random lenght, hence my answer). Makes sense after all. +1

Comment: @kos how about `base64 /dev/urandom | sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]/ /g'`?

Comment: I love it, extremely fast and it fits how I read initially the question, however I have to admit this had more sour of my mill than what has been actually explained, we really don't know. Also I noticed that for some reason your `base64 | sed` version produces more disproportion between words. Nice

Answer (score 4):

To generate a random alphabetic lower-case string (including spaces) of 2MB:

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-z ' | head -c 2000000 > a.log
```

For a constant stream:

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-z '
```

To generate a random alphabetic mixed-case string (including spaces) of 2MB:

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Za-z ' | head -c 2000000 > a.log
```

For a constant stream:

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Za-z '
```

Comment: Works, but needs a `| head -c #` at the end so that it gives a word at # number of characters long

Comment: @Terrance There you go

Comment: You got my +1.  :)  Works great!

Comment: Similar Ruby solution: `ruby -e '100.times do print [*?a..?z," "].sample; end'`

Answer (score 3):

An other version (`-c${1:-10}` = length of 10):

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z | head -c${1:-10} > out
```

or (`head -n 10` = length of 10)

```
strings /dev/urandom | grep -o '[[:alpha:]]' | head -n 10 | tr -d '\n' > out
```

or with `dd` (`count=10` = length of 10)

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=10 2>/dev/null | base64 | grep -o '[[:alpha:]]' | head -n 30 | tr -d '\n' > out
```

or this

```
openssl rand -base64 32| grep -o '[[:alpha:]]' | head -n 10 | tr -d '\n' > out
```

or this

```
date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | grep -o '[[:alpha:]]'| head -n 10 | tr -d '\n' > out
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my idea. `mkpasswd` is used often to generate encrypted passwords, hence the strings there shouldn't be intelligible already. The small problem is that it generates strings with numbers. By using sed, we can get rid of those.

`mkpasswd | sed 's/[0-9]/YOLO/g'`

YOLO could be whatever you want to substitute digits. You could also just delete them:

`mkpasswd | sed 's/[0-9]//g'`

Here's another way:

```
$ date | md5pass | sed 's/[0-9]//g'                                                                                                   
$$NG.dLw$vcpGCylnDtmptDtogDr/
```

As muru suggested in the comments bellow , you can also install `pwgen`, with `sudo apt-get install pwgen`, and run `pwgen -0`. The -0 flag tells the command to avoid numerals

And here's sha1pass + sed combo:

`sha1pass | sed 's/[[:digit:]]//g' | sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g'`
Result: `PoXGAlAWjzMHgmfzHiYHGpemzqE`

Another method with $RANDOM variable: `echo $RANDOM | tr '0-9' 'a-z'`

Overall, if your goal is password generation, I suggest you read this article:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30184/10-ways-to-generate-a-random-password-from-the-command-line/

Comment: `pwgen`! `pwgen -0` does this.

Comment: @muru yup, good one, but requires installation

Comment: Note `tr` is specially for this, no need to `sed`: `tr -d '[[:digit:]]`, etc.

Comment: I was not looking for a password generator approach but thanks so much for the info @ Serg. I did think about how this was done.  @ Serg.

Answer (score 3):

Using `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import random, string 
def rand_gen(number_of_words, length):
    for i in range(number_of_words):
        print ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(length))
    return
```

- We have defined a function `rand_gen(number_of_words, length)` that will take two parameters as inputs, `number_of_words` will contain the number of random words you want to generate, `length` will contain the length of each random word
- `string.ascii_lowercase` and `string.ascii_uppercase` have all the ASCII lowercase and uppercse letters respectively
- `random.choice` will choose a single character from `[A-Za-z]` each time and `length` will ensure that this iteration continues upto the `length` number. `join()` will then join the characters to have a word of desired length
- This process will be continued till `number_of_words`

**Example :**

```
rand_gen(5, 3)
PDI
qKQ
Dvu
kwr
wDz

rand_gen(2, 5)
GLKXr
uOaHj
```